# Redirecting to user profile page after creating a student

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following controllers:
**1- students_controller.rb**

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @students = Student.all
  end

  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    if @student.save
      flash[:notice] = ' Student Record Saved Successfully. Please fill the Parent Details.'
      redirect_to new_student_guardian_path(@student.id)
    else
      flash[:error] = 'An error occurred please try again!'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end
end
```

**2- guardians_controller.rb**

```
class GuardiansController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_student, only: [:new, :create]
  def index
    @guardian = Guardian.all
  end

  def show
    @guardian = Guardian.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @guardian = Guardian.new
  end

  def create
    @guardian = Guardian.new(params[:guardian])
    if @guardian.save
      flash[:notice] = ' Parent Record Saved Successfully. Please fill the Additional Details.'
      redirect_to new_student_previous_detail_path(@student)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'An error occurred please try again!'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  private
  def set_student
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  end

end
```

**3- previous_details_controller.rb**

```
class PreviousDetailsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_student, only: [:new, :create]
  def index
    @previous_detail = PreviousDetail.all
  end

  def show
    @previous_detail = PreviousDetail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @previous_detail = PreviousDetail.new
  end

  def create
    @previous_detail = PreviousDetail.new(params[:previous_detail])
    if @previous_detail.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Record Saved Successfully.'
      # redirect_to user profile page
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'An error occurred please try again!'
      redirect_to '/student/admission1'
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  private
  def set_student
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  end
end
```

**4- student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :add_to_users

  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guardians
  has_one :previous_detail
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :previous_detail

  def add_to_users
    new_user = User.new
    new_user.user_name = self.first_name
    new_user.first_name = self.first_name
    new_user.last_name = self.last_name
    new_user.email = self.email
    new_user.password = "123456"
    new_user.password_confirmation = "123456"
    new_user.user_type_id = 3
    new_user.save
  end
end
```

This callback is used to create the student in users model.

How can i tell the previous_details_controller.rb to go to the user profile page(the student who just created and also created in users model using the `after create :add_to_user`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem and I will add the slolution maybe will be helpful for anyone if needed.

**1- Modifying the callback method `add_to_user` to the following**

```
def add_to_users
    new_user = User.new
    new_user.user_name = self.first_name
    new_user.first_name = self.first_name
    new_user.last_name = self.last_name
    new_user.email = self.email
    new_user.password = "123456"
    new_user.password_confirmation = "123456"
    new_user.user_type_id = 3
    self.user_id = new_user.id
    new_user.save
    t = Student.find(self.id)
    t.user_id = new_user.id
    t.save
  end
```

so it will add the student to users model and also will update the user_id in student model to make a match between both.
also i have modified the name of callback above to `after_create :add_to_users , on: :create` to make sure it will raise on create action only.

**2- Modifying the create action in previous_details_controller where i need to redirect to user profile to the following**

```
def create
    @previous_detail = PreviousDetail.new(params[:previous_detail])
    if @previous_detail.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Record Saved Successfully.'
      redirect_to user_path(@student.user_id)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'An error occurred please try again!'
      redirect_to '/student/admission1'
    end
  end
```

after typing all this will redirect me to the User's profile page which belongs to the student who newly added to the system.